# Powering several 12 V @ 1A Vacuum Pumps

Tags: arduino, voltage, current, fluid-pump

I'd like to power several 12 V @ 1A vacuum pumps (and control them via Arduino).

For a few pumps, I assume a 12 V at 3.5 A adaptor would suffice?

Also, I'm currently using a TIP31C transistor (datasheet here: https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/TI/TIP31C.pdf), but the maximum current is only 3A, so I think I'll need something else here-- any suggestions?

Here's an image of the proposed circuit:

[image: http://i63.tinypic.com/25s0mkm.jpg]

Comment: Are you controlling them all simultaneously, or independently?  If independently, how many will run at one time?

Comment: Controlling them independently, but would like to be able to run three simultaneously.

Comment: Be aware that the pumps may briefly draw more than 1A while they are powering up due to [inrush current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inrush_current) so make sure that your adapter and transistors can handle this if the pumps do exhibit this behavior. Waiting for the previous pump to spin up before starting the next would also help control the current required of the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many is "several"?  You can operate three 1-amp loads from a 3.5A supply.  And if you are powering other circuit from the same supply, remember to factor those loads into the sum also.

Not clear whether you are saying that you want to operate ALL THREE loads on your TIP31. Clearly, the TIP31 is rated at 3A, which means that it can control three of these 1A loads combined.  And remember to use adequate heat-sink.

OTOH, using one transistor per load would be a much more conservative design.

Comment: Thanks! Say three pumps, for now... but I might eventually like to add more. So if I have three pumps, each drawing 1A, for a sum of 3A, a transistor with max 3A for all three would suffice... if I add more pumps, would you suggest another transistor with a greater maximum current than 3A? Or would it be best just to use one transistor for each pump?

Comment: If you want to control the pumps independently, you need one transistor for each pump.  If you think a single transistor would do what you want, you should show your proposed schematic (hit "control-M" to open the schematic editor while editing your question.)

Comment: Transistors are so dirt-cheap, I would use one transistor per load. That gives you much better flexibility for adding loads, etc. It is also safer. If something fails, it doesn't take everything else with it.

Comment: I added a diagram of the proposed circuit with a transistor per pump-- does this look correct?

Comment: Yes, that diagram looks generally correct. Just as a matter of convention, this is how the circuit is normally drawn:

http://blog.oscarliang.net/ctt/uploads/2013/10/image_thumb8.jpg